# databricks copy into xml files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to load some raw XML files from azure blob storage to delta table.

I have the blob container mounted already.

My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE bronze.my_xml_data;

COPY INTO bronze.my_xml_data
FROM 'dbfs:/mnt/my-container/data'
FILEFORMAT = XML
PATTERN = '*/some_dir/file_prefix_*.xml'
FORMAT_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema'='true', 'rowTag'='host', 'nullValue'='', 'valueTag'='val')
COPY_OPTIONS ('mergeSchema'='true')
```

I'm able to read the files with spark.read, so I'm sure the format options are correct.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
DeltaIllegalArgumentException: The format of the source files must be one of CSV, JSON, AVRO, ORC, PARQUET, TEXT, or BINARYFILE. Using COPY INTO on Delta tables as the source is not supported as duplicate data may be ingested after OPTIMIZE operations. This check can be turned off by running the SQL command `set spark.databricks.delta.copyInto.formatCheck.enabled = false`.
```

I tried with this option set to true, but then I got another error that table has no columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To load raw XML files from azure blob storage to delta table You can use below code.

```sql
%sql
CREATE  TABLE  temp_xml_data
USING  xml
OPTIONS (
path  "dbfs:/mnt/io234/sample.xml",
rowTag "book"
);
```

**Execution:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Will this automatically load incoming files like COPY INTO does?